# perl REGEX to match mutiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

Have issues in setting up a regex for multi-line match

Am trying to grab all failed queries ( receive status is 2 ) without success

Perl one line looks like

```
perl -e '$text = `cat errors.log`;while($text =~ m/^request.*?(\/.*?)\n.*?receive status is 2$/sgm ){print $1."\n";}'
```

Sample Log is as follows

```
***** test 0: *****
* Request:
request = /Lookup?url=URL1

received in 0.108 milliseconds
receive status is 2
-- STATUS : 1 --
      <RESULT SET 1>


***** test 1: *****
* Request:
request = /Lookup?url=URL2

received in 44.753 milliseconds
receive status is 0
-- STATUS : 0 --
      <RESULT SET 2>


***** test 2: *****
* Request:
request = /Lookup?url=URL3

received in 44.753 milliseconds
receive status is 2
-- STATUS : 3 --
      <RESULT SET 3>
```

Looking at grabbing all the URLs that have failed like URL1,URL3

Answer (score 3):

You should never use

```
`cat errors.log`
```

in Perl. Reading files is something that is simple and efficient in Perl, so learn it instead.

```
perl -lnwe 'BEGIN { $/= $/x3 } if (/receive status is 2/) 
            { print /request\s*=\s*(.+)/ }'  errors.log
```

Explanation:

- `-n` will treat the arguments to the script as file name arguments and open those files for reading.
- `-l` will handle line endings (for print here)
- The code inside `BEGIN` sets the input record separator to three newlines (or whatever your OS is using), which allows us to read the input file in chunks, reading up until three consecutive newlines.

And the rest is just two simple regexes. Because we spent some time making sure to keep the chunks separate, we can now use simpler regexes.

**Output:**

```
/Lookup?url=URL1
/Lookup?url=URL3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also simple with a bit of state:

```
perl -lne '$last = $1 if /request = (.+)/; print $last if /^receive status is 2/' errors.log
```

Storing the entire log in memory becomes less desirable as the log gets larger.  And logs have a way of getting to be fairly large.

Comment: This is simply cool :) can add more filters and grab whataver i want once we have failed segments

Comment: Thanks TLP,Daniel and all.nice thoughts to learn , shall bookmark this quest for future refrence :)